# How To Create Business Hours Via Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am creating a program that allows people to user to sign up their restaurants for a delivery program but, I'm trying implement methods that would allow users to enter their hours of operations when they sign up. So far I got this:

Models.py

```html
WEEKDAYS = [
    (1, _("Monday")),
    (2, _("Tuesday")),
    (3, _("Wednesday")),
    (4, _("Thursday")),
    (5, _("Friday")),
    (6, _("Saturday")),
    (7, _("Sunday")),
    ]

    weekday = models.IntegerField(
        choices=WEEKDAYS,
        unique=True
    )
    from_hour = models.TimeField()
    to_hour = models.TimeField()
```

Forms.py

```html
class RestaurantForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant

        fields = ("restaurant_name", "phone", "logo", "tagline", "street_address",
         "state", "city", "zip_Code","weekday", "from_hour", "to_hour")
```

But, when I run it, the options show ups up in an unusable format that doesn't allow the user to enter more than day and time:

[image]

I'm not sure what I should do to be able to setup this form and allow restaurants to add all the days and hours that they are opened or closed.

Comment: why the `unique=True` in the weekday field declaration.?

Comment: Honestly, I saw this work for someone else. I just tried it in my code.

Comment: You have data in your db_?

Comment: I currently have objects in my database. Just some test objects but, they don't have the fields.

Comment: i mean data. Do you have records in the database?

Comment: Yes. I currently have several test restaurant locations in my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168157/discussion-between-gytree-and-a-true-novice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new model `OpenningTime`

with the `week_day`, `from_hour`. `to_hour`

and then have a `ManyToManyField` in restaurant to `OpenningTime`.

now you can add multiple days to your restaurant

```
  WEEKDAYS = [
    (1, _("Monday")),
    (2, _("Tuesday")),
    (3, _("Wednesday")),
    (4, _("Thursday")),
    (5, _("Friday")),
    (6, _("Saturday")),
    (7, _("Sunday")),
 ]
class OpenningTime(models.Model):

    weekday = models.IntegerField(
        choices=WEEKDAYS,
        unique=True)
    from_hour = models.TimeField()
    to_hour = models.TimeField()

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    openning_times = models.ManyToManyField(OpenningTime)
```

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Comment: @ATrueNovice I updated the answer for the models, do you want an example for the form?

Comment: How is this called in forms?